# Replace ID number with corresponding name

Tags: ms-access

Basically, I have a table which looks like this:

```
Table: People
------------------------
ID | Employee 
------------------------
1  | Saul     
2  | Jess    
3  | Kenny
```

And then I have another table that looks like this:

```
Table: Projects
------------------------
ID | Project  | Employee
------------------------
1  | pro1     | 3
2  | pro2     | 1
3  | pro3     | 2
```

The problem is that I want to replace the numbers in the Employee column of the Projects table with the corresponding names of the employees in the People table.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace the ID Number, you need to build a query to show the results you want.

An example query can be:

```
SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.Project, People.Employee 
FROM Projects
INNER JOIN People on Projects.Employee = People.ID
```

This will result in:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | Project | Employee |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | pro1    | Kenny    |
|  2 | pro2    | Saul     |
|  3 | pro3    | Jess     |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Will this replace the ID number or just show the name without actually replacing it? I need to actually replace it.

Comment: It will not replace the ID number field, it joins the two tables to show you the data you need. If you really need to replace it: 1. then you'll need to add a fourth column 'EmployeeName` to the `Projects` table. 2. Then run an `Update` query to update the new column `EmployeeName` with the actual `Employee` from the `People` table. 3. Delete the column `Employee` from the `Projects` table. 4. Rename the column `EmployeeName` to `Employee` in the `Projects` table.

Comment: From a database perspective, we rarely change the field in the way you're requesting. Keep in mind if this is a running application these changes will probably break the app.